# How to rebind a Kendo ListView after changing template

Tags: javascript, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

I'm attempting to rebind the listview data after changing the template, based on a DropDownList value. I've included a JSFiddle for reference. When I rebind currently the values in the template are undefined.
Thanks!

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ripsin/MEXDt/)

I was thinking the best way to handle it would be in the 'select' or 'change' function:

```
var cboDetailsCategory = $("#detail").kendoDropDownList({
data: [
    "All",
    "Customer",
    "Location",
    "Meter",
    "Other"],
select: function (e) {

    var template = $("#" + e.item.text()).html();
    console.log("template", template);
    $("#details").html(template);       
},
change: function (e) {
},
```

please refer to the JSFiddle link and this graphic as a visual

[image: UI shown after name search is complete and user clicked on a name]

Here is a lengthier workflow:

1. User completes a name search and clicks a search button.
2. Name results are populated in a listview, rendered individually as button controls using a template.
3. User then clicks one of the name results (shown as the button text).
4. A dropdownlist of categories ('All' <--default , 'Location', 'Customer'...) gives the user the ability to target what subject of data they want to see. 'All' is the default, showing all details about the selected name.
5. So by default the 'All' template is populated.
6. If user wants to see the 'Location' details (template) they select it from the dropdownlist.
7. The template shows but the values are all blank. The only way to populate it is to click the name (button) again. 
   [image: Showing blank values in template after template changed]

I want to remove the need for having to re-click the button (name) to populate the template ('Location', etc...).

I have put together a JSFiddle showing the structure. Though due to the data being private and served over secure network I cannot access it.

Refer to JSFiddle:
I believe the issue is that the onclick event grabs the data-uid and passes it to the initial default template (named 'All' but it's not included in code as it's lengthy). When the user changes the dropdownlist (cboDetailsCategory) and selects a new template I lose the data.

Thanks for your help. I'm really stuck on this and it's a current show stopper.

Comment: sorry you want to update the Item template on the listview? After the dropdown select?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was convoluted.

Comment: @OnaBai and theporchrat I have updated this with information that may help further explain my issue. Thanks for both of your help!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an officially supported way to change templates, without destroying the listview and rebuilding it. However, if you don't mind poking into into some private api stuff (be warned I can't guarantee that kendo won't break it without telling you) you can do this

```
var listview = $("#MyListview").getKendoListView();

listview.options.template = templateString;

listview.template = kendo.template(listview.options.template);
//you can change the listview.altTemplate the same way 

listview.refresh(); //redraws the elements
```

if you want to protect against unknown API changes you can do this, which has A LOT more overhead, but no risk of uninformed change (untested!)

```
var listview = $("#MyListview").getKendoListView(),
    options = listview.options;


options.dataSource = listview.dataSource;

listview.destroy();

$("#MyListview").kendoListView(options);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to follow this with my example and how the .getKendoListView() fits in.

Comment: sorry getKendoListView() is equivalent  to $("#MyListview").data("kendoListView") it just gets the instance of the widget from the element. as an Aside your fiddle doesn't work at all, nor make any sense to me. you are using a hierarchical ds with the listview? that won't work correctly

Comment: Can I assume your commas in the first two lines are ; instead?

Comment: sorry fixed above! the second comma is a ; yes

Comment: Thanks. The hierarchical ds is being used with two templates as I needed treeview functionality and the ability to display the data similar to a (Visual Studio) properties window. The challenge is getting the value of "item" (which is the value from the button template, set with onClick, from UpdateDetails() to the DropDownList.

Comment: I've tried to tie in your logic above without any success. Hmmmpff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, thanks for everyone's help!
[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ripsin/CGdHJ/)

The issue was where I was setting the bind:

```
$("#list").on("click", ".k-button", function (e) {
    var uid = $(e.target).data("uid");
    var item = dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    var details = dropdown.value();
    var template = $("#" + details).html();
    $("#details").html(template);
    kendo.bind($("#details"), item);
    currentData = item;
});
```